# How can I remux FLV movies from YouTube (e.g. into MKV)?

Tags: video, youtube, matroska, flv, multiplexing

For some obscure reason, I have some video files I downloaded from YouTube as FLV rather than in another format. I would like to re-mux them into, say, MKV (Matroska). When trying to use ffmpeg, I get a `Unsupported video codec (7)` message. What should I do?

I'd like to be able to do this both in a command-line tool and through a GUI but either is fine.

My OS for the purpose of discussion is Windows XP SP3.

Comment: What's your OS? I was able to do this on CentOS but I had to build my copy of FFMPEG to get support for codecs like these.

Comment: Please show what exactly you tried with FFmpeg and include the full, uncut command line output. Without that it's hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: FLV is a video codec and MKV a video container, please specify the video codec you want to convert FLV to.

Comment: @Peter: FLV is not a video codec, it's a [container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video).

Comment: The codecs don't matter—FFmpeg can just copy them. `ffmpeg -i in.flv -c copy out.mkv` for example. What happens when you try that? Or, what was the command you tried before, including the full output?

Comment: @slhck: Thanks, it seems my problem was an outdated version of FFMPEG.

Answer (score 1):

(as @slhck suggests:)

FFMPEG can indeed remux FLVs into MKVs, regardless of the codecs used. But - this functionality is (relatively) recent, so:

1. Make sure you have an up-to-date version of FFMPEG. If you don't, download one from [the official site](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) (you might be referred off-site for [Windows builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)).
2. Run `X:\path\to\ffmpeg.exe -i input_file.flv -c copy output_file.mkv`

And that should work.